# Editing Distance between Abstract and Intro in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, line-spacing, abstract

Here's an example of how I'd like my abstract to appear.

[image]

Note that the amount of vertical space between the abstract and intro is minor. In my document the vertical space between the abstract and intro is rather large. I've tried to manually edit the vertical length by using single spacing or custom spacing between the abstract and the intro, but I did not notice any difference.

**Source Code of Intro and Abstract:**

```
\begin{abstract}
\begin{doublespace}
\noindent Abstract\end{doublespace}

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{\noindent INTRODUCTION}
```

**Source Code of Entire Document:**

```
 \documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{setspace}

 \makeatletter
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}
 \numberwithin{figure}{section}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
 \title[Short version]{Long version}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \makeatother

 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{abstract}
 \begin{doublespace}
 \noindent Abstract\end{doublespace}

 \end{abstract}
 \maketitle

 \section{\noindent INTRODUCTION}
 \end{document}
```

How can I edit the vertical space between the abstract and the intro?

Comment: Adding a `\vskip x cm` just before `\end{abstract}` should do the trick.

Comment: @Bernard how can I enter it there? The only way I know to  how to enter vertical space is by using the tabs. How can I edit the source code to do this?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment. I'm looking to shrink the vertical space. Let me edit the question to clarify that since I haven't yet.

Comment: Add a negative skip. For instance `\vskip -2\baselineskip`.

Comment: It's OK with me. I don't think it is of a sufficiently general interest to be turned into an answer.

Comment: @Bernard I am trying to enter it again, but it is no longer working. I enter the evil red text in the abstract or immediately after (either in Abstract mode or Standard mode) but the vertical space isn't changing, even if I use numbers other than -2.

Comment: Just is case, try `\mbox{}\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}` (with the *).

Comment: Btw, you don't have to use evil red text. You can insert vertical space in Lyx via `Insert > Formatting Vertical Space...`. Then choose a percentage of line width, for example.